# Is there any superset API to open dashboard?

Tags: apache-superset

I have been using superset. I want to bypass the login page. To do so I did the following in a js file

1. Got token using login API
2. Got dashboard URL using dataset find API

I have tried to open the dashboard url and I am getting login page eventhough I already hit login API to get the tokens. I want to know is there any way or build in API in superset to open the superset dashboard bypassing the login page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This proposal on the Superset repo might be relevant to your use case https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/17187

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your support. I have implemented SSO in superset. I have done the following things hope it might be helpful for others.

1. Inside security folder create your own login/logout method inside init.py file.
2. Update CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER from None to your custom class(defined inside security folder).

I have followed this link https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/master/flask_appbuilder/security/manager.py.